# Is Communicating Sequential Processes ever used in large multi threaded C++ programs?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently writing a large multi threaded C++ program (> 50K LOC).

As such I've been motivated to read up alot on various techniques for handling multi-threaded code. One theory I've found to be quite cool is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes

And it's invented by a slightly famous guy, who's made other non-trivial contributions to concurrent programming.

However, is CSP used in practice? Can anyone point to any large application written in a CSP style?

Thanks!

Comment: lol @50k loc being large

Comment: [PySCP](http://code.google.com/p/pycsp/) looks like a viable practical implementation of CSP. Some examples are included. Though, at the moment it is reportedly used only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CSP, as a process calculus, is fundamentally a theoretical thing that enables us to formalize and *study* some aspects of a parallel program.

If you instead want a theory that enables you to *build* distributed programs, then you should take a look to *[parallel structured programming](http://www.di.unipi.it/europar04/ColePisa04.pdf)*.

Parallel structural programming is the base of the current HPC (high-performance computing) research and provides to you a methodology about how to approach and design parallel programs (essentially, flowcharts of communicating computing nodes) and *runtime systems* to implements them.

A central idea in parallel structured programming is that of *algorithmic skeleton*, developed initially by Murray Cole. A skeleton is a thing like a parallel design pattern with a cost model associated and (usually) a run-time system that supports it. A skeleton *models*, *study* and *supports* a class of parallel algorithms that have a certain "shape".

As a notable example, *mapreduce* (made popular by Google) is just a kind of skeleton that address data parallelism, where a computation can be described by a *map* phase (apply a function f to all elements that compose the input data), and a *reduce* phase (take all the transformed items and "combine" them using an associative operator +).

I found the idea of parallel structured programming both theoretical sound and practical useful, so I'll suggest to give a look to it.

A word about multi-threading: since skeletons addresses massive parallelism, usually they are implemented in distributed memory instead of shared. Intel has developed a tool, [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/), which address multi-threading and (partially) follows the parallel structured programming framework. It is a C++ library, so probably you can just start using it in your projects.

Comment: The funny thing is, CSP now is the hottest concurrent mechanism being used in programming :)

Comment: @nXqd: I've been using Go's form of it for 7 years, and I can't say it's working out. I don't know if it differs from CSP, but there are a lot of flaws and better ways to do things.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. The basic *idea* of CSP is used quite a bit. For example, thread-safe queues in one form or another are frequently used as the primary (often only) communication mechanism to build a pipeline out of individual processes (threads).

Hoare being Hoare, however, there's quite a bit more to his original theory than that. He invented a notation for talking about the processes, defined a specific set of signals that can be sent between the processes, and so on. The notation has since been refined in various ways, quite a bit of work put into proving various aspects, and so on.

Application of that relatively formal model of CSP (as opposed to just the general idea) is much less common. It's been used in a few systems where high reliability was considered extremely important, but few programmers appear interested in learning (yet another) formal design notation.

When I've designed systems like this, I've generally used an approach that's less rigorous, but (at least to me) rather easier to understand: a fairly simple diagram, with boxes representing the processes, and arrows representing the lines of communication. I doubt I could really offer much in the way of a proof about most of the designs (and I'll admit I haven't designed a really *huge* system this way), but it's worked reasonably well nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the website for a company called [Verum](http://www.verum.com). Their ASD technology is based on CSP and is used by companies like Philips Healthcare, Ericsson and NXP semiconductors to build software for all kinds of high-tech equipment and applications.

So to answer your question: Yes, CSP is used on large software projects in real-life.

Full disclosure: I do freelance work for Verum

Answer (score 2):

Answering a very old question, yet it seems important that one

There is [Go](https://golang.org) where CSPs are a fundamental part of the language. In the [FAQ to Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#csp), the authors write:

> Concurrency and multi-threaded programming have a reputation for difficulty. We believe this is due partly to complex designs such as pthreads and partly to overemphasis on low-level details such as mutexes, condition variables, and memory barriers. Higher-level interfaces enable much simpler code, even if there are still mutexes and such under the covers.
>
> **One of the most successful models for providing high-level linguistic support for concurrency comes from Hoare's Communicating Sequential Processes, or CSP.** Occam and Erlang are two well known languages that stem from CSP. Go's concurrency primitives derive from a different part of the family tree whose main contribution is the powerful notion of channels as first class objects. Experience with several earlier languages has shown that the CSP model fits well into a procedural language framework.

Projects implemented in Go are:

- [Docker](https://docker.com)
- [Google's download server](https://talks.golang.org/2013/oscon-dl.slide#1)
- [Many more](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Projects)

Answer (score 0):

This style is ubiquitous on Unix where many tools are designed to process from standard in to standard out.  I don't have any first hand knowledge of large systems that are build that way, but I've seen many small once-off systems that are

for instance this simple command line uses (at least) 3 processes.

```
cat list-1 list-2 list-3 | sort | uniq > final.list
```

Comment: Yes, but the pipeline is not between processes, not between threads like the OP is asking about.

Comment: The paper he links to is about processes.

Comment: CSP as a theory doesn't care about the distinction between threads and programs. The question as stated still remains valid: is CSP theory used in practice, in multi-threaded programs?

Answer (score 0):

This system is only moderately sized, but I wrote a protocol processor that strips away and interprets successive layers of protocol in a message that used a style very similar to this.  It was an event driven system using something akin to cooperative threading, but I could've used multithreading fairly easily with a couple of added tweaks.

The program is proprietary (unfortunately) so I can't show off the source code.

In my opinion, this style is useful for some things, but usually best mixed with some other techniques.  Often there is a core part of your program that represents a processing bottleneck, and applying various concurrency increasing techniques there is likely to yield the biggest gains.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft had a technology called ActiveMovie (if I remember correctly) that did sequential processing on audio and video streams. Data got passed from one filter to another to go from input to output format (and source/sink).  Maybe that's a practical example??

Comment: not really, one thread is used to push data all the way through the chain of filters.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article looks to me like a lot of funny symbols used to represent somewhat pedestrian concepts. For very large or extensible programs, the formalism can be very important to check how the (sub)processes are allowed to interact.

For a 50,000 line class program, you're probably better off architecting it as you see fit.

In general, following ideas such as these is a good idea in terms of performance. Persistent threads that process data in stages will tend not to contend, and exploit data locality well. Also, it is easy to throttle the threads to avoid data piling up as a fast stage feeds a slow stage: just block the fast one if its output buffer grows too big.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit off-topic but for my thesis I used a tool framework called [TERRA/LUNA](http://www.ce.utwente.nl/ECSSoftware/) which aims for software development for Embedded Control Systems but is used heavily for all sorts of software development at my institute (so only academical use here).
TERRA is a graphical CSP and software architecture editor and LUNA is both the name for a C++ library for CSP based constructs and the plugin you'll find in TERRA to generate C++ code from your CSP models.
It becomes very handy in combination with [FDR3](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/projects/fdr/) (a CSP refinement checker) to detect any sort of (dead/life/etc) lock or even profiling.